# How to check if dimension value is available on all days in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have two input dimensions i.e. Day and Product_sold and I want to create a calculated field "Flag" in Tableau. Basically Flag will show "Yes" if the product was sold on all days, else No (see example attached), can you please help? I have tried multiple things but no use

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a fixed LoD calculation to count distinct number of days in data. Then used another fixed LoD (or possibly a table calc) to count distinct days for each product. If the product COUNTD = dataset COUNTD than it sold on every day.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? This looks like a simple attribution calc that could be put together as boolean eg:

```
Product_sold = 'computer'
```

Steve

Comment: Please read the problem statement again.. My actual data is thousands of lines and i dont  know which product was sold on all days. So the I am looking for some smart solution where it tells automatically instead of knowing it was computer

Comment: I am trying to help you, you have provided no real data, a workbook, or any real information about what you've so far tried, so I need to start with the basics and build up as I have no idea as to your knowledge with Tableau, which is why I assumed you are asking here rather than over at the Tableau community.
So lets start from the top: you tell me your actual requirement, your data structure, and what you've so far tried, and I shall try and help you